# Calculating mathematical functions in Android

Tags: java, android, function, math

I'd like to build myself a small app to get my homework done faster. I want the user to be able to enter any function like f(x)=x<sup>2</sup>-5x+3 or f(x)=x<sup>3</sup>/(2x-2) and then return a list of y-values for specific x-values. For f(x)=x<sup>2</sup> it would look something like this:

- x=-2 y=4
- x=-1 y=1
- x=0  y=0
- x=1  y=1
- x=2  y=4
- x=3  y=9
- x=4  y=16

And so on. Is there any function in the math class of java that takes in a mathematical function and an x-value and outputs the according y-value or do I need to have some kind of parser of my own?

**Edit**

[exp4j](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/index.html) seems to be the right thing for me. This library is very small, fast and easy to use.

Comment: You can build an expression parser in ANTLR: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589951/parsing-an-arithmetic-expression-and-building-a-tree-from-it-in-java or use the JVM's scripting facilities, as is shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681959/algebra-equation-parser-for-java

Comment: You can run this kind of thing through WolframAlpha, e.g. [`evaluate f(x)=x^2-5x+3z for x=4`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=evaluate+f%28x%29%3Dx^2-5x%2B3z+for+x%3D4), but building your own parser is a lot more fun. ANTLR is a good place to start.