# Java ArrayList String Separation

Tags: java, string, arraylist, integer, substring

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SplitString 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s = "80+5+3*(11%(3*2)-(5+1)+6)-(10+10)+(2*2)*5";
        ArrayList<String> equation = new ArrayList<>();
        String ns = "";
        String b;
        int nsi;

        for(int c=0; c<s.length(); c++)
        {
             b = s.substring(c,c+1);
            switch (b) {
                case "0":
                case "1":
                case "2":
                case "3":
                case "4":
                case "5":
                case "6":
                case "7":
                case "8":
                case "9":
                    ns += b;
                    break;
                case "+":
                case "-":
                case "*":
                case "/":
                case "%":
                case "(":
                case ")":
                    nsi = Integer.parseInt(ns);
                    equation.add(Integer.toString(nsi));
                    equation.add(b);
                    ns = "";
                    break;
            }

             for(int i=0; i<equation.size(); i++)
             {
                 System.out.print(equation.get(i));
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to split the String s into separate numbers and operators within an `ArrayList` in such a way that if a number like `00080` is entered, it will assume the number as `80` instead. But I'm having trouble, and when I run this it gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
80+80+80+5+80+5+80+5+3*
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at stringequationfull.StringEquationFull.main(StringEquationFull.java:42)
Java Result: 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure you want to use a switch?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to parse an empty string as an int; hence the exception. Your logic for dealing with operators is wrong. Your code assumes that there is always a number between operators, but if you look at your equation, this is clearly not the case. (Look at occurrences of parentheses.) The exception is being raised because, as the message states, `ns` is the empty string.

You will need to develop a more general parsing logic. Search the web for "parse equation java" for lots of examples of how to do this. If you just want the ability to evaluate equations, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681959/algebra-equation-parser-for-java) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/java-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number).

Answer (score 4):

`nsi = Integer.parseInt(ns);` will [throw](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29):

> NumberFormatException - **if the string does not contain a parsable
>   integer.**

Debug your code and you'll see that `ns` **doesn't** contain a parsable integer. (Hint: it is empty)

*Tip*: The *[stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688068/how-to-read-and-understand-the-java-stack-trace)* is very informative, you can easily know *where* the problem occurred and *why* did it occur. A simple investigation will lead you to the problem. In this case, it's an exception that was thrown from *parseInt* (Class Integer), you can see there a good documentation of the method. This will help you a lot to find out what is your problem.