# Is it possible to find how many letters are used in a string?

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string and I want to use some formulas, in which there is a word that is going to be searched. Sometimes that word could be in different place, depending on the user. In order to make substrings work, I have to ensure that when it happens, the code still works.

```
 String temp = s;//Temp is a long string text       

     String fehlerspeicher="fehlerspeicher";
    if(temp.matches(".*"+fehlerspeicher+".*")){
    // i have to find as an integer, how many LETTERS are used till this spesific word
    }//to make changes in the following code
    String temp1=temp.substring(0, 15000);//15000 is an example. it can be 5000 or 20000 sometimes. It splits the text up from 15000th letter.
    String temp2=temp.substring(15000);// It'd be useful to use this integer in these 2 formulas.
    temp2=temp2.replaceFirst("200", "20_");
    temp=temp1+temp2;
```

So, could it be somehow implementable? Thanks.

Comment: You should use a formula parser library or even better, use JavaScript as shown here: [Algebra equation parser for java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4681959/1065197).

Comment: Maybe `indexOf()` combined with the length of `fehlerspeicher` will help you

Comment: I did not get the part about the 15000 can you explain it more?

Comment: @mosaad 15000 is an example. it can be 5000 or 20000 sometimes. It splits the text up from 15000th letter and then I use it in substring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use indexOf:

```
public int indexOf(String str)
```

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
>   specified substring.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

So to get the index of "fehlerspeicher" you can use:

```
int index = temp.indexOf("fehlerspeicher");
```

So to get the position of the 'f' in 'fehlerspeicher' you can use:

```
String temp = "hellofehlerspecher";    //example temp string
int index = temp.indexOf("fehlerspeicher");
int fPos = index + 1; //fpos will equal 6.
```

Comment: I dont need the index of string actually. I need how manieth letter is "f" of "fehlerspecher "in this string text.So i can put it in substring and make it work in every possibility

Comment: I'm confused, is the index (the location in the string) of fehlerspeicher not what you are looking?

Comment: Edited my queston with another example